Continuation of: "Multiple choice questions with proposed answers in random order — addition of automatic correction (cross mark)"
This is about the post.
Is it possible to create a list of questions on one page and then show the same list on the next page with answers included? When I try to do this, the questions on the second page with the answers get rearranged. How can I keep the questions in the same order on both pages?
Here is an example:
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{lmodern}                      % or whatever you want
 % To make small pages for the screenshots:
 \usepackage[paperwidth=15cm, paperheight=11cm,
        hmargin=2cm, vmargin=1cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[italian]{babel}
 \usepackage{siunitx}                      % only for the examples
 \usepackage{xparse}                       % only for the 'test' environment
 \usepackage[shuffle-questions, shuffle-answers]{sebmcq} % your new package :-)

 \pagestyle{empty}

 \sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

 \ExplSyntaxOn
 \NewDocumentEnvironment { test } { m +b }
   { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 \clearpage } }
   { }
 \ExplSyntaxOff
 
 %\ShowCorrectAnswers
 
 \begin{document}
 
 \begin{test}{4}
 \begin{questionnaire}
 % Mark the correct answer with either [x] or [X]. If no mark is      present, the
 % correct answer is assumed to be the freeform one.
 \question{Q 1}{
 {Option 1}
 [X]{Option 2}
 {Option 3}
 {Option 4}
 }
 
 \question{Q 2}{
 {Option 1}
 {Option 2}
 {Option 3}
 [X]{Option 4}
 }

 \question{Q 3}{
 [X]{Option 1}
 {Option 2}
 {Option 3}
 {Option 4}
 }
 \end{questionnaire}
 \end{test}

 \end{document}

The sebmcq.sty can be found in here.
